# Mount /home dir from specific directory from external drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, 20.04, home-directory

I currently have a Windows system (on an SSD, let's call it `C:\`) where all the user files (the `${USERNAME}\` dir) are on a separate internal drive (under `E:\${USERNAME}\`).

I will be moving to Ubuntu permanently (maybe I'll make a dual boot setup with Windows or maybe I'll be playing just with VMs, I haven't figured it out yet) and I want to do the following:

Since most (if not all) the directories under `${USERNAME}\` in Windows share the same names as their equivalents in Ubuntu, I would like to setup my Ubuntu installation like that:

So that the `/home` dir mounts the `E:\${USERNAME}` for its contents.

Is this something that is possible, and if so, how?

One thing I can think of, is to manually symlink each of the dirs under `/home` to their equivalent in `E:\${USERNAME}` but I was wondering if there is a better/less manual way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are thinking of, manually symlink dirs, is by far the best and most secure one, except that you should not link the entire user home directory.

In Linux, each user has a home directory, /home/$USER (with $USER the login of the user). This contains folders to user data (Documents, Videos, ...). It also contains user configuration data in hidden files and folders, i.e., files and folders where the name starts with a dot. The latter may require specific permissions to be set. Therefore, they must live on a partition that fully supports linux permissions.

Therefore, I would leave the home directory on a file system that fully supports the linux file permissions. You can then replace the folders to user data (Documents, Videos, ...) with links pointing to their equivalents on your C:\ drive.

Comment: I ended up /w a dual boot setup, and I made both Win and Ubuntu look at `E:${USERNAME}` for `Documents`, `Downloads`, `Videos`, `Music`, `Pictures`. In ubuntu I created symlinks and placed them in `${HOME}/` (deleting the original folders) and in Windows you have the option to "move" those folders. The filesystem on that drive is NTFS so both OSs can read/write data there. Everything works fine, except I had to disable fast boot in Windows, because it marks the volume as if it was in hibernation and makes it unavailable in Ubuntu. But the OS lives in an M2 drive, so no biggie in terms of speed